# How to create a dataframe from text file having single column

Tags: python, pandas

This question might have asked by someone else also but as I couldn't able to find solution for my question, so I'm writing here, hope someone could help me.

## Question

I've text file in that, all column data has been below one another, how to split those data and create a table.

## Example- Students data.

SlNo

1

2

3

4

Student Name

A

B

C

D

Grade

First

Second

Third

Fourth

Subject

English

Mathematics

Science

Physics

Marks Obtained

50

65

55

70

Percentage

10%

20%

30%

40%

Above is the sample data on single column(like one below another) and in a text file.

## How to create a dataframe from text file and split the columns

My code as follows but I'm not getting anything

```
import pandas as pd

def parse_my_file(filename):
  With open ('sample.txt')as f:
      for line in f:
         yield line.strip(). split (' ',1)


 df=pd.DataFrame(parse_my_file('sample.txt'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.loadtxt('test1.txt',delimiter = '\n\n', dtype=str)
reshaped = x.reshape(-1,5).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data = reshaped[1:,:], columns = reshaped[0])

print(df)
```

OR

```
def parseFile(filename, vals_per_col):
    with open('test1.txt','r') as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
    return {lines[i]:lines[i+1 : i+5] for i in range(0,len(lines),vals_per_col+1)}

df = pd.DataFrame(parseFile('sample.txt',4))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  SlNo Student Name   Grade      Subject Marks Obtained Percentage
0    1            A   First      English             50        10%
1    2            B  Second  Mathematics             65        20%
2    3            C   Third      Science             55        30%
3    4            D  Fourth      Physics             70        40%
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply! But I'm getting error... reshaped=x.reshape(-1,5).T......   Cannot reshape array of size 188 into share (5)

Comment: That must mean your file has different pattern. Either there are extra lines at the top or bottom, or there are different values per column.

Comment: I tried you're second program,it's working but I'm getting [4rows x 36columns]... I've lots of lines but 6column heads... any help could matter.... And how to save that to csv

Comment: Could you provide a link to the file and your code?

Comment: Appreciate for help, sorry I can't upload it, due to data security...... It's a text file all data are below one another 
without gaps as showed on above example but have more rows like 1-40

Comment: Try: `lines[i+1 : i+41]` in the return and then call `pd.DataFrame(parseFile('sample.txt',40))` , see if that does it

Comment: Do we have anyway to create columns as per columns name's for example...when SlNo completed and get student name ...it should iterate till name completes and create next column with next column head

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, Hope this will help,

```
import pandas as pd

def parse_my_file(filename):
  all_ele = []
  with open ('data.txt')as f:
      for line in f:
          # print(line.strip().split(' ',1))
          if line.strip().split(' ',1)[0] != '':
            all_ele.append(line.strip().split(' ',1)[0])
  return all_ele



all_ele = parse_my_file('data.txt')

new_data = { (all_ele[i-5] if i!= 0 else all_ele[0]):(all_ele[i-4:i] if i != 0 else all_ele[1:i+5]) for i in range(0,len(all_ele)+5,5) }
print(new_data)

df=pd.DataFrame(new_data)
print(df)
```

Saving data into csv file.

```
df.to_csv(<path>,index=False)
```

Ouput will be :

```
{'SlNo': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Student': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Grade': ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'], 'Subject': ['English', 'Mathematics', 'Science', 'Physics'], 'Marks': ['50', '65', '55', '70']}


  SlNo Student   Grade      Subject Marks Percentage
0    1       A   First      English    50        10%
1    2       B  Second  Mathematics    65        20%
2    3       C   Third      Science    55        30%
3    4       D  Fourth      Physics    70        40%
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I'm getting output but I've more rows..how to get all I'm getting only 4rows x 36columns...   How to make only 6 columns and rows are number of records... How to save that file

Comment: df.to_csv(<path>,index=False),  If you are getting more rows, then it is issue data in your file.

Comment: Sorry to create confusion, I mean I've 36rows in text file but on your program I'm getting only 4rows

Comment: Do we have any way to auto create columns on the basis of their column names.... For example:- from above if SlNo completed and detect student Name it should create a new column till it detect next column text