# Data formatting in DataFrame from vertical column

Tags: python, pandas

I couldn't find something like this enough to understand what to do and I'm pretty new to python programming:

So I pull this information from a spreadsheet using some loose scraping parameters:

```
WI ASM #
HOLDER #
HOLDER DESCRIPTION
A.63.140.1/8z
A.63.140.1/8z
A.63.140.1/8z
A.63.140.1/8z
A.63.140.1/8z
CUTTER #
Harvey 980215
Harvey 980215
Harvey 28178
Harvey 28178
Harvey 74362-C3
OPERATION
GROOVE
ROUGHING
SEMI-FINISH
FINISH
DEBURR & BLEND
TOOL DESCRIPTION
CREM_.125_.015R_1
CREM_.125_.015R_2
CREM_.0781_.015R_1
CREM_.0781_.015R_2
BEM_.0625
```

All I want to do is format this data from the list of str's that I have, into a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
WI ASM #    HOLDER #     HOLDER DESCRIPTION  CUTTER #          OPERATION        TOOL DESCRIPTION     
                         A.63.140.1/8z       Harvey 980215     GROOVE           CREM_.125_.015R_1
                         A.63.140.1/8z       Harvey 980215     ROUGHING         CREM_.125_.015R_2
                         A.63.140.1/8z       Harvey 28178      SEMI-FINISH      CREM_.0781_.015R_1
                         A.63.140.1/8z       Harvey 28178      FINISH           CREM_.0781_.015R_2
                         A.63.140.1/8z       Harvey 74362-C3   DEBURR & BLEND   BEM_.0625
```

The long column of data is stored in "storage":

```
for i in range(len(row_list)):
        k = 1
        storage.append(header_list[i])
        while na_finder.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] == True and df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] is not header_list:
            store = df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]]
            storage.append(df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]])
            k += 1
```

So I have a header titles list, a rows and columns list with the scraped data's location in the DataFrame. I'm just trying to format the output like I showed, but I can't get it in the horizontal format like that with the specific column titles. Can anyone help me build this, where instead of turning everything into lists I turn it into the formatted dataframe?

***EDIT: I am able to get it into the dataframe now, however...***
So I updated the code I posted to this:

```
for i in range(len(row_list)):
        k = 0
        while na_finder.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] == True and df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] is not header_list:
            if(df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] not in header_list):
                outdf.at[i+k, header_list[i]] = df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]]
            k += 1
```

Now the main issue is that my dataframe wont format nicely:

```
{'WI ASM #': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'HOLDER #': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'HOLDER DESCRIPTION': {3: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 4: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 5: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 6: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 7: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'CUTTER #': {3: nan, 4: 'Harvey 980215', 5: 'Harvey 980215', 6: 'Harvey 28178', 7: 'Harvey 28178', 8: 'Harvey 74362-C3', 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'OPERATION': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 'GROOVE', 6: 'ROUGHING', 7: 'SEMI-FINISH', 8: 'FINISH', 9: 'DEBURR & BLEND', 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'TOOL DESCRIPTION': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: 'CREM_.125_.015R_1', 7: 'CREM_.125_.015R_2', 8: 'CREM_.0781_.015R_1', 9: 'CREM_.0781_.015R_2', 10: 'BEM_.0625', 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'Starting Radial Wear': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: '-', 8: '-', 9: '-', 10: -0.0002, 11: '-', 12: nan, 13: nan}, 
'TOOL STICK OUT': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: 0.55, 9: 0.55, 10: 0.55, 11: 0.55, 12: 0.55, 13: nan}, 
'TOOL LIFE (MIN)': {3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: 120, 10: 120, 11: 120, 12: 240, 13: 300}}
```

How do I remove all the NaN's and move the existing data up? I've tried outdf.dropna() but it just deletes all of my data.

Comment: just saw your post. have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971209/how-to-create-a-dataframe-from-text-file-having-single-column) I think it solves your problem. In general, it isn't recommended to fill a DataFrame in loops line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using Pandas:

```
hdrs = ['WI ASM #','HOLDER #','HOLDER DESCRIPTION','CUTTER #','OPERATION','TOOL DESCRIPTION']
```

Create a mask that identifies the header rows:

```
hdr_msk = df[0].isin(hdrs)
```

Then replicate headers in a new column across all data rows:

```
df['hdr'] = df.loc[hdr_msk][0]
df['hdr2'] = df['hdr'].ffill()

                     0                 hdr                hdr2
0             WI ASM #            WI ASM #            WI ASM #
1             HOLDER #            HOLDER #            HOLDER #
2   HOLDER DESCRIPTION  HOLDER DESCRIPTION  HOLDER DESCRIPTION
3        A.63.140.1/8z                 NaN  HOLDER DESCRIPTION
4        A.63.140.1/8z                 NaN  HOLDER DESCRIPTION
5        A.63.140.1/8z                 NaN  HOLDER DESCRIPTION
6        A.63.140.1/8z                 NaN  HOLDER DESCRIPTION
7        A.63.140.1/8z                 NaN  HOLDER DESCRIPTION
8             CUTTER #            CUTTER #            CUTTER #
9        Harvey 980215                 NaN            CUTTER #
.....
.....
23  CREM_.0781_.015R_1                 NaN    TOOL DESCRIPTION
24  CREM_.0781_.015R_2                 NaN    TOOL DESCRIPTION
25           BEM_.0625                 NaN    TOOL DESCRIPTION
```

Then pivot the table and move all values to the top of each column:

```
df.pivot(columns='hdr2',values=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)[1:])[hdrs].fillna('')

  WI ASM # HOLDER # HOLDER DESCRIPTION         CUTTER #       OPERATION    TOOL DESCRIPTION
1                        A.63.140.1/8z    Harvey 980215          GROOVE   CREM_.125_.015R_1
2                        A.63.140.1/8z    Harvey 980215        ROUGHING   CREM_.125_.015R_2 
3                        A.63.140.1/8z     Harvey 28178     SEMI-FINISH  CREM_.0781_.015R_1 
4                        A.63.140.1/8z     Harvey 28178          FINISH  CREM_.0781_.015R_2 
5                        A.63.140.1/8z  Harvey 74362-C3  DEBURR & BLEND           BEM_.0625
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm just new at python and eventually figure out my own questions, so here is what I did and the output will follow:

```
for i in range(len(row_list)):
        k = 0
        while na_finder.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] == True and df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] is not header_list:
            if(df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]] not in header_list):
                outdf.at[k, header_list[i]] = df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]]
            k += 1
```

All I changed was in the line:

```
outdf.at[i+k, header_list[i]] = df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]]
```

The outdf.at[i+k...] made the output super wonky, so I changed it to:

```
outdf.at[k, header_list[i]] = df.at[row_list[i] + k, column_list[i]]
```

And now the output looks like:

```
{'WI ASM #': {1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}, 'HOLDER #': {1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}, 
'HOLDER DESCRIPTION': {1: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 2: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 3: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 4: 'A.63.140.1/8z', 5: 'A.63.140.1/8z'}, 
'CUTTER #': {1: 'Harvey 980215', 2: 'Harvey 980215', 3: 'Harvey 28178', 4: 'Harvey 28178', 5: 'Harvey 74362-C3'}, 
'OPERATION': {1: 'GROOVE', 2: 'ROUGHING', 3: 'SEMI-FINISH', 4: 'FINISH', 5: 'DEBURR & BLEND'}, 
'TOOL DESCRIPTION': {1: 'CREM_.125_.015R_1', 2: 'CREM_.125_.015R_2', 3: 'CREM_.0781_.015R_1', 4: 'CREM_.0781_.015R_2', 5: 'BEM_.0625'}, 
'Starting Radial Wear': {1: '-', 2: '-', 3: '-', 4: -0.0002, 5: '-'}, 
'TOOL STICK OUT': {1: 0.55, 2: 0.55, 3: 0.55, 4: 0.55, 5: 0.55}, 
'TOOL LIFE (MIN)': {1: 120, 2: 120, 3: 120, 4: 240, 5: 300}}
```

Which is exactly what I was looking for.